# Removing Header and Footer and grey color background from the converted PDF file using Headless chrome

Tags: google-chrome-headless

I am using headless chrome to convert web page into pdf through cli commands.But in the generated pdf file along with my content header, footer and grey color background are included. I am trying to remove them from the PDF file. Is there any commands are provided with headless chrome to do that?

[image: Generated PDF]